# TinyMCE's value in bean on second submit (using jsf.ajax.addOnEvent)

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, tinymce

I have set up a basic testcase in which I'm experience some (to me) weird behaviour. When using the setup below, the typed value in the editor will only be visible by `h:outputText` on the second submit. E.g.

- Change value in editor to "myvalue"
- Send Ajax-request
- h:outputText shows "test" (default value from bean)
- Change value in editor to "anothervalue"
- Send Ajax-request
- h:outputText shows "myvalue"
- Send Ajax-request
- h:outputText shows "anothervalue"

Note: there's a custom composite, please ask for code if needed (it simply creates textarea for TinyMCE and loads .js file from below)

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <mh:editor id="tinymceEditor" 
                   value="#{bean.value}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Ajax">
            <f:ajax execute="tinymceEditor" 
                    render="show" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:outputText id="show" value="#{bean.value}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**jsfhandler.js** -> included on header in custom composite mh:editor

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    switch(data.status) {
        case "begin":
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true,"tinymceEditor");
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
            break;

        case "complete":
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl',true,"tinymceEditor");
            break;

        case "success":            
            break;
    }
});
```

**Bean.java**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    private String value = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSF ajax `begin` event is too late in order to take changes in form data into account. The ajax request is already prepared based on form data before this event.

Effectively, the sequence is as follows:

- User enters input (and leaves field).
- HTML DOM "change" event is triggered on input field.
- User clicks submit button.
- HTML DOM "click" event is triggered on submit button.
- JSF prepares ajax request.
- JSF ajax "begin" event is triggered on ajax request.
- JSF sends ajax request.
- ...

Basically, you should be doing `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` during the HTML DOM "click" event.

```
<h:commandButton ... onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave()">
```

Or, better, during the HTML DOM "change" event of the tinyMCE textarea.

Comment: I was trying to avoid any onclick event on the submit. Though I can try to use a change event on the textarea itself. Thanks, the way JSF works behind the scenes is become clearer with every function I need to implement (and therefor often an answer you provide).